# Pattern based sql query

Tags: sql, window-functions

A Table:

```
col1          col2          col3           col4
17            5678          abc            mno
16            5678          abc            mno
15            5678          abc            mno
14            5678          abc            mno
13            5678          abc            mno
10            1234          def            pqr
```

I want to create a column `output` with either value 'a' or 'b'

```
 col1          col2          col3           col4           output
 17            5678          abc            mno            b
 16            5678          abc            mno            a
 15            5678          abc            mno            b
 14            5678          abc            mno            b
 13            5678          abc            mno            a 
 10            1234          def            pqr            a
```

For a partition by (or group) of columns namely `col3, col4` and order by `col1 and col2`, output is marked the value of 'a' the first occurrence of that group (row 5 for example), this row marks an event which can last 3 consecutive times, after which again `output` column should be marked 'a' (example, row 2) if col1 is in sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
select t.*,
  case mod(row_number() over (partition by t.col3, t.col4 order by t.col1, t.col2), 3) 
    when 1 then 'a'
    else 'b'
  end output
from tablename t 
order by t.col1 desc
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b7b2333c64c8def6d953669639f173e6).
Results:

```
> COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | OUTPUT
> ---: | ---: | :--- | :--- | :-----
>   17 | 5678 | abc  | mno  | b     
>   16 | 5678 | abc  | mno  | a     
>   15 | 5678 | abc  | mno  | b     
>   14 | 5678 | abc  | mno  | b     
>   13 | 5678 | abc  | mno  | a     
>   10 | 1234 | def  | pqr  | a
```

Comment: select t.*,
  case mod(row_number() over (partition by t.col3, t.col4 order by t.col1, t.col2), 3) 
    when 1 then 'a'
    else 'b'
  end output
from TABLE1 t ORDER BY 1 DESC;

Comment: Correct order by

Comment: Do you mean ORDER BY Col1 DESC? You can apply whichever order you want.

Comment: `ORDER BY 1` returns this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=dbc4aa9156fdb56108e953d48e04fe49

Comment: select t.*,
  case mod((row_number() over (partition by t.col3, t.col4 order by t.col1, t.col2)), 3) 
    when 1 then 'a'
    else 'b'
  end output
from tablename t  
order by 1 desc

Comment: As I said ORDER BY is your choice. But I never use numbers in the ORDER BY clause. I prefer column names/aliases.

Comment: Yes I agree Name/aliases are standard way of doing it. I have ordered it by col1 desc to match exactly as per user requirement.

Comment: Thanks @forpas, is there a way we do output='a' only when col1 is consecutive. For example, if there is a row after row 5 with col1=11, then this row also to be marked as 'a' since it is not consecutive

Comment: This is a new requirement, so you must provide sample data that covers this case also and expected results in a new question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem.  You need to enumerate the rows in the islands and then some conditional logic:

```
select t.*,
       (case when mod(row_number() over (partition by col3, col4, seqnum - seqnum_2 order by col1, col2), 3) = 1
             then 'a' else 'b'
        end) as
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by col1, col2) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by col3, col4 order by col1, col2) as seqnum_2
     from t
     ) t;
```